# Make a Ubuntu Server ready for takeoff as a webserver

Tags: server, webserver, nginx

What are the necessary steps to make an ubuntu server ready for productive operation as a webserver? I've assumed that the server distro of ubuntu doesn't have to be further tweaked to make it ready for productive operation as a webserver (nginx in my case). However, though ready enough there are some things that need to be set up. What I've learned to do are:

- Set swappiness = 0
- Increase max number of open files for the webserver

My knowledge ends here... What are the other parameter that I have to consider for a successful productive operation of a webserver?

Comment: The [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/) has some good information about setting up a server.

Comment: That's indeed a very good resource. But it doesn't go deep enough to cover this kind of topics..

Comment: If you want more depth in an answer, you will need to give us more information about what you plan on using the server for.

Comment: I want to use the Server to run a django application with a nginx in front. I'll use a postgresql database elasticsearch as search engine. Initially elasticsearch will run on the same server.